# execution out of order inside ajax callback function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynccallback

I have a following ajax operation that is intended to `(1) show spinner gif` before sending `ajax` request, and after after the request is complete, `(2) hide` the gif and `3 display` appropriate alert messages. 
Finally `(4) reload` the page.

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: rUrl,
   data: {
      id: rID,
      requisitionStatus: rStatus,
      comment: rComment
   },
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function() {
      $("#requisitionStatusDialog").dialog('close');
      $('#ajax_loader_my').show();
   },
   success: function(data, resp) {
      var json = data;
      var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
      if (obj.status == "success") {
         alert('Success! ' + obj.message);
         location.reload();
      } else if (obj.status == "error") {
         alert('Error!' + obj.message);
      }
   },
   error: function(data, resp) {
      $("#updateDialog").dialog('close');
      console.log(resp);
   },
   complete: function() {
      $('#ajax_loader_my').hide();
   }
});
```

But in this case, `alert` pops up first while the `spinner gif` still shows up, and `reloads` the page after clicking `OK`.

I even tried `hiding` the gif in `success` callback itself instead of using `complete`:

```
success: function(data, resp) {
  var json = data;
  var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
  if (obj.status == "success") {
     $('#ajax_loader_my').hide();
     alert('Success! ' + obj.message);
     location.reload();
  } else if (obj.status == "error") {
     alert('Error!' + obj.message);
  }
```

},

Both gives the same result.

Comment: write $('#ajax_loader_my').hide(); at the starting of the success function and then try

Comment: @RK_15 the same..

Comment: This is happening because $(...).hide() is asynchronous.

Comment: Use $('#ajax_loader_my')[0].style.display = "none" and then try

Comment: Or use $('#ajax_loader_my').hide(0,()=>{alert('Success! '+obj.message);
      location.reload();}); This will execute the rest of the code after animation for hide stops

Comment: @RK_15 still the same.. the loader still shows up even after alert pops up..

Comment: Have you tried $('#ajax_loader_my').hide(0,()=>{alert('Success! '+obj.message); location.reload();});

Comment: you will need to move `$('#ajax_loader_my').hide();` in the `success:` callback &  remove it from the `complete:`.

Comment: @techie_28 yeah that I have tried...and also mentioned in the post..

Comment: @Azima did you moved the hiding line as the first thing in your `success:`?

Comment: @techie_28 yeah.. as RK_15 had already mentioned..

Comment: @Azima I suggest you update that attempt in the question also.

Comment: @Azima, Please try my updated answer. Instead of alerts, try to use some inline html to display the success or error, or may be log into console.

Comment: Can you please show us some html where the image is located ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the code this way, this will put your alert and location related code in event queue which will run when it will be free.

```
if(obj.status=="success") { 
      $('#ajax_loader_my').hide(); 
      setTimeout(function(){
          alert('Success! '+obj.message);
          location.reload();
      },0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your alert pops up before the spinner is hidden is the success code runs before complete which hides the spinner.  The reason it reloads is because after the alert you send location.reload();

Check that $('#ajax_loader_my').hide(); is actually hiding the spinner.  The element that is or contains the spinner in your html must be have its id set to ajax_loader_my.

If you open Chrome or Firefox Dev tools you should be able to send $('#ajax_loader_my').hide() and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should try to use promises here is the documentation [Jquery promises](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), I made this on the fly it can have some errors but is just an example:

```
$( function() {
  function AjaxCall(rID,rStatus,rComment){
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'request.php',
      data: {
        id: rID,
        requisitionStatus: rStatus,
        comment: rComment    
      },
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#requisitionStatusDialog").dialog('close');
        $('#ajax_loader_my').show();
      }
    })
  }


  $( "#requisitionStatusDialog" ).dialog();

  $("#yourbuttonInputId").on('click',function(event) {
    AjaxCall().done(function(data,response){
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      if (obj.status == "success") {
        alert('whe are on done!');
      }
    }).fail(function(data,response){
      $("#updateDialog").dialog(' close');
    }).always(function(data){
      if(confirm('You have finished the request.  Click OK if you wish to continue ,click Cancel to reload the page.'))
      {
        $('#ajax_loader_my').hide();
        $("#requisitionStatusDialog").dialog('open');
      }else{
        location.reload();
      }

    });
  });
} );
```

**EDIT:** Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhke5pt/1/) it will guide you to elaborate your code

Hope it Helps

Answer (score -1):

I would rather suggest to use an empty div or span with an Id.
Than display success in the html of that div.
For Example:

```
$('#ajax_loader_my').hide();    
setTimeout(function () { 
    $('#successDiv').html('Success! ' + obj.message);
    location.reload();
}, 2000);
```